# Tailwind CSS not Rendering in Docker Desktop Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, tailwind-css, docker-desktop

I am developing a Docker Desktop extension and I am able to get it running locally as desired, but when I create the actual extension, i.e. the Docker image, the Tailwind CSS I am using does not render correctly.

What could be the reason for this?

This is my simple `index.html` file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="relative flex w-full content-center min-h-screen flex-col justify-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12 items-center ">
        <svg class="animate-pulse"  width="94" height="52" viewBox="0 0 94 52" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <!-- paths -->
        </svg>
        <p class="mt-6 text-zinc-800">Hang tight! The service is starting..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `index.css` looks like this,

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I have a simple JavaScript function in my `index.js` that checks if the service at my address is running and redirects the user to that address when it is,

```
function checkServer() {
    fetch('http://my-address')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Server not ready');
        }
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
        window.location.href = 'http://my-address';
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Server not ready yet. Wait for 2 seconds and try again
        setTimeout(checkServer, 2000);
      });
  }

  window.onload = checkServer;
```

I have used this [guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) to install and configure Tailwind CSS and all of the generated files are included in my Docker image (`tailwind.config.css` and `postcss.config.css` are included within the `ui` directory).

Finally, this is my `Dockerfile`,

```
FROM node:18-alpine
#labels

COPY docker-compose.yaml .
COPY metadata.json .
COPY ui ui

RUN cd ui && npm install
```

The rest of my code is within the `src/ui` directory.When I `cd` into my `ui` directory and run `npm run dev`, the service runs without any problem. However, when I create a container out of it and run it as an extension on Docker Desktop, it does not work. In fact, I realized that the JavaScript function I have is not correctly routing the application to my address either.

Prior to adding Tailwind CSS, this worked fine; both locally and on Docker Desktop.

Comment: Where are you actually running the tailwind commands to generate the css?

Comment: Locally. I ran the commands and it generated the config files. Is it not enough to bundle these files in the project?